# Remove rows based on thier date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a really big excel list with 2000+ records.

I use this code to sort the date:

```
   Range("C1") = "Dates"
   Columns("A:E").Sort key1:=Range("C2"), _
   order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

So when this executes, I now got a really big list with on top the date of today and the previous dates underneath that. Now I would like to delete all the dates/records before yesterday.

So if today is `12/29/2020` its needs to delete everything starting with `12/27/2020` and so on.

The dates are displayed in `column C`, in this format `12/29/2020  1:26:55 PM`

Comment: You should use a date filter instead of just a descending sort.

Comment: Great idea, but this excel list gets generated by a system. So what I'm trying to do is create a template where you just can copy, paste the records and press one button so it all gets sorted out.

Comment: You can use a date filter with VBA. The fact that this list is generate by a system is not relevant here. In other words, use `Range.AutoFilter` instead of `Range.Sort`.

Comment: Thanks I'll checl it this is going to work.

Comment: Thank man this works also kinda sorta it out hehe thanks for the tip!

Comment: To finish the answer to your question, if you autofilter for yesterday and older, as @BigBen suggests, then you can delete visible rows using special cells like:

```ActiveSheet.Range("A:E" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete```

Or if you have a header row in your range that you don't want to delete, add an offset to the range to exclude it:

```ActiveSheet.Range("A:E" & lastrow).Offset(1,0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete```

Comment: Hey man thanks for your answer! I already used a filter on the headers that works perfect thanks tho!